# Powershell script to alternate enabling disabling a network card

Tags: powershell

I did some searching and put together the following script, but it doesn't do anything.  It will display DISABLING INTERNET but then just closes, and doesn't actually disable the card. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
# This Powershell Script will alternate enabling and disabling the Network Card
# Change NAME OF NETWORK CONNECTION with the actual name of your network connection from control panel

$up = "Up"
$disconnected="Disconnected"
$lan = "NAME OF NETWORK CONNECTION"

$landown = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $disconnected -and $_.Name -match $lan }
$lanUp = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $up -and $_.Name -match $lan }

if ($lanUp)
{
    Write-Host("Disabling Internet")
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
elseif ($landown) 
{
    Write-Host("Enabling Internet")
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
Exit
```

===========================
Original post

I don't know much about powershell.  I have used devcon and a script which i created a shortcut to which will alternate enabling and disabling the network card on several desktops for an easy way to disconnect from the internet/network when not needed.  Since upgrading from win 7 to 10, one computer occasionally cannot re-enable it's network card without a reboot (even when going to device manager.  after being disabled it will once in a while stop working).  Someone on reddit suggested it may be an issue with devcon and how it unloads the driver.  It was suggested using a powershell script.

I have searched and found commands to enable or disable a network adapter and how to get adapter information.  But I am looking for a single script to check the status of the adapter and either enable or disable it depending on what the current status is.  And hoping this will stop the issue from happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Search using this... 'Powershell  disable network card' powershellgallery.com, you'll find samples, or just use the cmdlets --- Disable-NetAdapter --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/disable-netadapter?view=win10-ps --- Enable-NetAdapter --- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/enable-netadapter?view=win10-ps --- Otherwise, you are asking for to do your work for you. That's not what folks do here. You have to show your work, errors, etc, and more will be inclined to help.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added some code above and am asking for help.  I hope that is enough to re-open my post and allow people to comment.  I'm not sure how everything works around here.  Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, except for when re-enabling the network adapter. You are using the wrong string for `.Status` when the interface is not Up. If you look at a Disabled network adapter (hint: `Disable-NetAdapter`) you can see that the `Status` property has a value of 'Disabled', not 'disconnected'. This is why it works when your interface is 'Up' but not when it is 'Disabled'. Replace your code with the following:

```
$up = "Up"
$disabled = "Disabled"
$lan = "NAME OF NETWORK CONNECTION"

$landown = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $disabled -and $_.Name -match $lan }
$lanUp = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $up -and $_.Name -match $lan }

if ($lanUp)
{
    Write-Host("Disabling Internet")
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
elseif ($landown) 
{
    Write-Host("Enabling Internet")
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
Exit
```

I would fix that first, then further troubleshoot other issues (such as your theory about the driver) if it does not begin to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you I had missed that.  It still wasn't working but I realized it wasn't running as admin.  So I created a shortcut and set it to run as admin.  Now when I run the shortcut, and click ok on UAC prompt, the script works.  I had noticed 2 things.  On this one computer, after a reboot, instead of disabled the adapter showed as Not Present.  Once enabled and disabled again, then it showed as disabled.  Also, the powershell window wasn't closing so I had to add another line (after research to get it to close.  My final script is below.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Final Script.  Works when I create a shortcut to it and set the shortcut to run as admin.
Thank you

```
# This Powershell Script will alternate enabling and disabling the Network Card
# Change NAME OF NETWORK CONNECTION with the actual name of your network connection from control panel
# Example "Local Area Network"

$up = "Up"
$disabled = "Disabled"
$notpresent = "Not Present"
$lan = "NAME OF NETWORK CONNECTION"

$landown = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $disabled -and $_.Name -match $lan }
$landown2 = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $notpresent -and $_.Name -match $lan }
$lanUp = Get-NetAdapter | select Name,Status | where { $_.Status -match $up -and $_.Name -match $lan }

if ($lanUp)
{
    Write-Host("Disabling Internet")
    Disable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
elseif ($landown) 
{
    Write-Host("Enabling Internet")
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
elseif ($landown2) 
{
    Write-Host("Enabling Internet")
    Enable-NetAdapter -Name $lan -Confirm:$false
}
stop-process -Id $PID
Exit
```